# Jmeter script is working fine for single user but failures at multiple users and not able to retrieve response from server

Tags: jmeter

My application end to end scenarios are working with single user iteration with all  post processors data working fine But when I increase multiple users in thread group and run the same scenario..scripts getting failed in the middle due to some requests are not properly executed leads correlation fails...attached my scripts and error message, scripts files located at below drive link

https://drive.google.com/open?id=13IPlVh-Zi2AJOioGeCuHihyxYiDeRBLK

Please help me how to resolve this issue, as this is highly important to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

You're not being able to click any order from the search results as there are no order search results - there are simply no orders to choose from as you're **not getting logged in by 2nd user**

[image]

My expectation is that this is due to wrong test structure, i.e. you have the requests like:

- `/login_check`
- `/user/showInfoBox`
- etc.

under the Parallel Controller however the Parallel Controller's children are being executed **at the same time**.

Real browser first executes `login_check` request followed by `/` followed by `index.php`, so you should put only `css` and `ajax` calls under the Parallel Controller otherwise you may run into the situation when the [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) calls are being fired already and you haven't been logged in yet.

Check out [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more information on JMeter tests troubleshooting techniques.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, You are the one who always help me out in any problem of jmeter when I post question, I will correct my scripts as you suggested and let you know if problem resolves, Thanks a lot once again!!!

Comment: My confusion  here is if single user working fine..why it happens to multiple users...is there any particular configuration or timers needs to be added in the script.?